# undefined method `where' in ruby on rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

i have two  tables table1 and table2 with has_many belongs_to relation ( table1 has many table2 and table2 belongs to table1) i write the value like that `table2.table1.where(.....)`
but i have the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<table1:0xc59764c>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `table2` belongs to `table1`, then calling `table2.table1` will give you a single object of type `table1`. You can't call `where` on a single object (nor does it make sense to do so), only on a table or relation.